# Composer installs a package not present in .json file

Tags: json, bash, laravel, composer-php

I am using Laravel 5.4 with composer and when i try to install some requirement bash tells me:

> Package illuminate/html is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laravelcollective/html instead.

Which is perfectly ok, illuminate/html is abandoned and i replaced it with the laravelcollective/html package in composer.json file, which is included in the following code snippet, but the problem is that even though illuminate/html is not present in composer.json file, it is installed when i issue the composer update command in console. I am very new to Laravel fw, but i also managed to remove illuminate/html from aliases and providers arrays in config/app.php file. I also tried several times manually removing illuminate/html folder from the vendor directory, which succeeded, but with new composer update it returns...

> How can i delete this package and ensure, that it wont install itself next time i add new package with composer?

PS: I am not sure whether it has something to do with my problem, but i also had problem with post-update-cmd, which i replaced from previous "php artisan optimize" to "php customisan.php", where customisan.php will clear folder bootstrap/cache and all of its content.

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "illuminate/support": "^5.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/passport": "^2.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
    "yajra/laravel-oci8": "^5.4"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php customisan.php"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
}
```

}

Comment: try composer dump-autoload

Comment: Did you install it with `composer install`? This installs from composer.lock file, whatever changes you made to composer.json won't be affected. You need to run `composer update` "commit" changes to composer.json file.

Comment: @devk I installed it by manually writing it down into composer.json file and then running One by one all Netbeans integrated composer options (install dev, install no-dev, update no-dev, update dev) later i found the composer update cmd for console so i began using that...

Comment: @Rodrane composer dump-autoload did not help.

Comment: @devk ok, i messed up. I copy pasted without actually looking at code, i wasnt using composer update, but composer install and yes composer update made things ok for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If anyone experiences similar problem, @devk's answer should help.

All i had to do was issue **composer update** command in console.
Further explanation provided in @devk's answer...